# Plaid Account Id can change in some Instance

Tags: java, plaid

I was going through plaid docs and I found this "In some instances, account IDs may change." So now I am curious how can i uniquely identify an account.  ref https://plaid.com/docs/api/ in the Item Management section.

I want to uniquely identify an account because that is what user selected to use as primary account.

Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: See https://support.plaid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008271954-Account-id-overview

Answer (score 0):

I believe mostly it will be unique unless some changes are applied in the bank side like removing/adding account type to the existing ones. Also even if we use same account more than once, plaid will assign unique ID as account_id each and every time.

I prefer, you should go by the account & routing number and not by the account_id returned by plaid. Account_id is mainly used for plaid reference.

Answer (score 0):

Plaid has a document about **[Preventing duplicate Items](https://plaid.com/docs/link/duplicate-items/)**.

Quoting from the document (emphasis mine):

> You can compare a **combination of the accounts’ institution_id, account name, and account mask** to determine whether an end user has previously linked an account to your application. Do not exchange a public token for an access token if you detect a duplicate Item.

You can catch these at link time and avoid linking, or you can store them in a database as a primary key on the three:

```
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| institution_id     | varchar(255)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| account_name       | varchar(255)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| account_mask       | varchar(255)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
```

If you do this, you will need to ensure there are no NULL fields. I use "empty" for NULL items in the "account_mask" column.

It is also a good idea to use the item remove API on the old item_id when you do need to make a duplicate, such as the old item_id no longer works.

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is an old question, but I just wanted to confirm for anyone who finds this that the account_id is not a unique identifier. Instead, the access_token should be used to identify an account in your database.

If you're using plaid/dwolla to initiate ACH payments, the dwolla funding URL is the best identifier of the account.

Comment: And how does that contradict my comment? OP is asking how to uniquely identify an account, not what is needed to make API requests.